# VS Code Search and Quick Open having problems

Tags: visual-studio-code

I updated VS Code recently to version 1.63.2  Since the update, my Quick Open and Search in files is weird.  First, when I search in files, it displays results as expected, but there's a little active search indicator that is ALWAYS moving across and never stops.

When I do a Quick Open (ctrl + p) that is only showing recently opened file and not all files in the workspace.  It also constantly has a search indicator moving across the screen.

Any idea how to fix this?  If I do a quick open and type in "PaymentInstrument" I expect to find all files with that in the name across my workspace and that is not the case now.  Only shows recent files.  I've played around with the quick open settings with no success.  Rebooted the ole machine, no success.

thanks!

Comment: I still don't know why this was happening, but I closed my workspace and opened the folder and resaved a new workspace and all is working now.  I'm a bit unfamiliar with what is saved in the workspace, but happy it's working.

Comment: Was having the same problem and closing and re-opening the workspace worked for me. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

reopening the workspace didn't work here, but I've found out that quick open feature (ctrl + P) applies the exclusions from .gitignore and .ignore files.
checking and unchecking the Use ignore files setting in search options fixed this issue for me.